# Indian RMO (Regional Math Olympiad) $2011$ Problem $4$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Consider a $20$-sided convex polygon K, with vertices $A_1, A_2, . . . , A_{20}$ in that
> order. Find the number of ways in which three sides of K can be chosen so
> that every pair among them has at least two sides of K between them.

Now in [this](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/rmo-2011-solutions.pdf) solution, at the end, for finding number of triples that is $(78 × 20)/3$, why we divided by $3$ here ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the triple $({A_1A_2, A_8A_9, A_{15}A_{16}})$. It was counted when $A_1A_2$ was the first side and also when $A_8A_9$ was the first side and when $A_{15}A_{16}$ was the first side.

So every valid triple has been counted thrice.